# Template specialization on template member of template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, specialization

This is probably only a syntax problem.

So i have this template class :

```
template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator>
class basic_data_object
{
  template<typename T>
  using array_container = std::vector<T, Allocator<T>>;
};
```

And another one :

```
template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator, typename T>
struct get_data_object_value
{
};
```

Now i want to specialize the second one's `T` parameter with the first one's inner typedef `array_container` for any given type.

```
template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator, typename T>
struct get_data_object_value
<String, Allocator,
typename basic_data_object<String, Allocator>::template array_container<T>>
{
};
```

But this specialization doesn't seem to be matched when i pass an std::vector as the last parameter.

If i create a temporary hard coded typedef:

```
typedef basic_data_object<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>> data_object;
```

And use it for the specialization, everything works :

```
template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator, typename T>
struct get_data_object_value
<String, Allocator,
data_object::template array_container<T>>
{
};
```

What did i miss ? :)

---

Alternatively what is the best (smallest / cleanest) way to make this work ?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) - so basically clang 3.4 i guess :)

Comment: +1; you have me stumped. I suspected a missing `typename` but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: The short code that reproduces the problem outputs "specialization" only in [vc++2013](http://rextester.com/GUC17610). Both [gcc 4.8.1](http://rextester.com/QFLZIG32455) and [clang 3.4](http://rextester.com/EDWPM93123) outputs "general".

Comment: Looks like a non-deduced context, though I'd guess that compilers should then emit a warning. AFAIK, template type parameters are deduced independently, and you can't deduce `String` and `Allocator` from the last argument.

Comment: @dyp But both of them also appear as first two arguments as I can see.

Comment: @Constructor True, so you could manually make it a two-step deduction by using a nested template. However I think being a non-deduced context simply disables deduction for the third parameter, even if it could be deduced using the first two.

Comment: Is there any way to make it work (the nested template stuff might be interesting) ?

Comment: Well, I give up: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3670b6413e6c26be

Comment: @MooingDuck Instantiations of alias templates are not treated as .. well .. instantiations of alias templates. They're treated as the types they alias. Therefore AFAIK your `is_instantiation_of` doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I do not see the problem... Code seems to work: http://ideone.com/qmfIMb

Comment: @Danvil The code compiles, but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: I reduced the [issue](http://ideone.com/K18pLl) further: removing `template <class> class Allocator` from everywhere and yet it still fails; thus `Allocator` is not part of the problem.

Comment: Jonathan Wakely nailed the issue you are facing on the head! Regarding finding an actual solution though, I am afraid we have too few elements. I suggests that you ask a separate question, providing more *context* and specifically what is the problem those classes are supposed to solve, why is the specification required, and what classes we can (and cannot) modify to assist you. Maybe with a more complete view, we could provide a more elegant solution as well.

Comment: I forgot to mention than thanks to Jonathan I had thoroughly changed my answer to include a layman's interpretation of what's going on in the compiler; hopefully this should make it much clearer what's going on here and thus help shape out future answers to avoid the same woes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer of Jonathan Wakely gives the reason why your code does not work.

My answer shows you how to solve the problem.

---

In your example, the container type over which you want to specialize is defined outside of `basic_data_object` thus you can of course use it directly in your specialization:

```
template <typename S, template<class> class A, typename T>
struct get_data_object_value<S,A,std::vector<T,A>>
{ };
```

This definitely conforms with the standard and works with all compilers.

---

In the case where the type is defined in `basic_data_object`, you can move it out of the class.

**Example:** Instead of

```
template<typename S, template<class> class A>
struct a_data_object
{
    template<typename T>
    struct a_container
    { };
};
```

write this:

```
template<typename S, template<class> class A, typename T>
// you can perhaps drop S and A if not needed...
struct a_container
{ };

template<typename S, template<class> class A, typename T>
struct a_data_object
{
    // use a_container<S,A,T>
};
```

Now you can specialize with:

```
template <typename S, template<class> class A, typename T>
struct get_data_object_value<S,A,a_container<S,A,T>>
{ };
```

---

**Note**: The next "solution" is apparently a bug with GCC 4.8.1.

If the container is only defined in an enclosing template and can not be moved out you can do this:

1. Get the container type out of `basic_data_object`:

   ```
   template<typename S, template<class> class A, typename T>
   using bdo_container = basic_data_object<S,A>::array_container<T>;
   ```
2. Write a specialization for this type:

   ```
   template <typename S, template<class> class A, typename T>
   struct get_data_object_value<S,A,bdo_container<S,A,T>>
   { };
   ```

Comment: `basic_data_object<S,A>::array_container<T>` should be `typename basic_data_object<S,A>::template array_container<T>`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Constructor: Oh well, now it's back to digging in the standard I suppose.

Comment: Interesting work-around; unfortunately just *aliasing* will not get you out of this because aliases are just sugar-coating here, the deduction/resolution still occur on the underlying types.

Comment: By the way your previous code does not compile with clang 3.4 at [coliru.stacked-crooked.com](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/40efb24a0e708c6c).

Comment: @Constructor: GCC seems to be confused about when template and typedef is required...

Comment: I guess you meant `a_container`instead of `a_data_object` in the 3rd code sample of the second part ?

Comment: @Drax: Thanks for noting the mistake! I fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

The C++ standard says, in [temp.class.spec.match] paragraph 2:

> A partial specialization matches a given actual template
>    argument list if the template arguments of the partial
>    specialization can be deduced from the actual template
>    argument list (14.8.2).

14.8.2 is [temp.arg.deduct] i.e. the clause describing template argument deduction for function templates.

If you modify your code to use a similar function template and attempt to call it, you will see that the arguments cannot be deduced:

```
template <typename String, typename T>
void deduction_test(String,
                    typename basic_data_object<String, std::allocator>::template array_container<T>)
{ }

int main()
{
  deduction_test(std::string{}, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>{});
}
```

(I removed the `Allocator` parameter, since there's no way to pass a template template parameter as a function argument and in the `basic_data_object` type it's a non-deduced context, I don't believe it affects the result.)

Both clang and GCC say they cannot deduce `T` here. Therefore the partial specialization will not match the same types used as template arguments.

So I haven't really answered the question yet, only clarified that the reason is in the rules of template argument deduction, and shown an equivalence with deduction in function templates.

In 14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type] we get a list of *non-deduced contexts* that prevent deduction, and the following rule in paragraph 6:

> When a type name is specified in a way that includes a non-deduced context, all of the types that comprise that type name are also non-deduced.

Since `basic_data_object<String, Allocator>` is in a non-deduced context (it is a *nested-name-specifier*, i.e. appears before `::`) that means the type `T` is also non-deduced, which is exactly what Clang and GCC tell us.

---

With your temporary hardcoded typedef there is no non-deduced context, and so deduction for `T` succeeds using the `deduction_test` function template:

```
template <typename String, typename T>
void deduction_test(String,
                    typename data_object::template array_container<T>)
{ }

int main()
{
  deduction_test(std::string{}, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>{}); // OK
}
```

And so, correspondingly, your class template partial specialization can be matched when it uses that type.

---

I don't see a way to make it work without changing the definition of `get_data_object_value`, but if that's an option you can remove the need to deduce the `array_container` type and instead use a trait to detect whether a type is the type you want, and specialize on the result of the trait:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator>
class basic_data_object
{
public:
  template<typename T>
  using array_container = std::vector<T, Allocator<T>>;

  template<typename T>
    struct is_ac : std::false_type { };

  template<typename T>
    struct is_ac<array_container<T>> : std::true_type { };
};

template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator, typename T, bool = basic_data_object<String, Allocator>::template is_ac<T>::value>
struct get_data_object_value
{
};

template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator, typename T>
struct get_data_object_value<String, Allocator, T, true>
{
  void f() { }
};

int main()
{
  get_data_object_value<std::string,std::allocator,std::vector<short>> obj;
  obj.f();
}
```

This doesn't really scale if you wanted several class template partial specializations, as you would need to add several `bool` template parameters with default arguments.

Comment: Function template specialization works differently than class template specialization.

Comment: @Danvil, my answer does not mention function template specialization, because I'm not talking about function template specialization. However, class template partial specialization relies on template argument deduction, which works the same as for function templates. The standard says so.

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, deduction for classes is different than for functions.

Comment: No, I can't see that. Where am I meant to see that? The quote I gave from the standard even has a reference from [temp.class.spec.match] to [temp.arg.deduct]. Can you quote from the standard to support your claim (N.B. there is no "deduction for classes", I chose my words carefully when I said "class template partial specialization _relies_ on template argument deduction")

Comment: There are a lot of specific rules in [temp.class.spec] (14.5.5) which apply only to classes. Does that not mean that it works differently?

Comment: The only part of 14.5.5 that mentions "deduction" is 14.5.5.1, which is where I got the quote in my answer, which refers to 14.8.2, so I don't know what you're talking about, sorry. In any case, my answer shows a direct correspondence between matching partial specializations and argument deduction for function templates, when one fails, the other fails, and when one succeeds the other succeeds. Can you prove otherwise?

Comment: If you change the definition of `array_container` to `using array_container = std::vector<int>;` (no longer a template, so some adaptations are necessary) then the OP code works and the specialization is elected. Thus I challenge the *non-deduced context* claim made here -- *You can check 3 simplified code examples in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23431650/147192).*

Comment: You brilliantly explained what is happening thus answering the main first part of the question, a viable workaround is missing though :). I'll therefore wait for the bounty to end so you will earn half of it.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason, the problem seems to stem from the double level of templates. I'll leave you check the 3 test cases below, they are simple:

1. Remove the template arguments of `First`: works as expected
2. Make `First` a template, but the inner type a plain one: works as expected
3. Make both `First` and the inner type templates: compiles but the output is unexpected

*Note: the template template parameter `Allocator` is useless to reproduce the issue, so I left it out.*

*Note: both GCC (ideone's version, 4.8.1 I believe) and Clang (Coliru version, 3.4) compile the code, and yet produce the same baffling result*

<strike>From the 3 above examples, I deduce:</strike>

- <strike>that this is NOT a non-deducible context issue; otherwise why would (2) work ?</strike>
- <strike>that this is NOT an alias issue; otherwise why would (1) work ?</strike>

<strike>And therefore that either the problem is much hairier than the current hints would make us believe OR that both gcc and Clang have a bug.</strike>

**EDIT**: Thanks to Jonathan Wakely who patiently educated me enough that I could finally understand both the Standard wording related to this case and how it applied. I will now attempt to explain this (again) in my own words. Please refer to Jonathan's answer for the exact Standard quotes (it all sits in **[temp.deduct.type]**)

- When deducing template parameters (P<sub>i</sub>), whether for functions or classes, **the deduction is done independently for each and every argument**.
- Each argument need provide zero or one *candidate* C<sub>i</sub> for each parameter; if an argument would provide more than one *candidate*, it provides none instead.
- Thus, each argument produces a dictionary D<sub>n</sub>: P<sub>i</sub> -> C<sub>i</sub> which maps a subset (possibly empty) of the template parameters to be deduced to their candidate.
- The dictionaries D<sub>n</sub> are merged together, parameter by parameter:

  - if only one dictionary has a candidate for a given parameter, then this parameter is accepted, with this candidate
  - if several dictionaries have the same candidate for a given parameter, then this parameter is accepted, with this candidate
  - if several dictionaries have different incompatible (*) candidates for a given parameter, then this parameter is rejected
- If the final dictionary is complete (maps each and every parameter to an accepted candidate) then deduction succeeds, otherwise it fails

(*) there seems to be a possibility for finding a "common type" from the available candidates... it is of no consequence here though.

Now we can apply this to the previous examples:

1) A single template parameter `T` exists:

- pattern matching `std::vector<int>` against `typename First::template ArrayType<T>` (which is `std::vector<T>`), we get D<sub>0</sub>: `{ T -> int }`
- merging the only dictionary yields `{ T -> int }`, thus `T` is deduced to be `int`

2) A single template parameter `String` exists

- pattern matching `std::vector<int>` against `String`, we get D<sub>0</sub>: `{ String -> std::vector<int> }`
- pattern matching `std::vector<int>` against `typename First<String>::ArrayType` we hit a non-deducible context (many values of `String` could fit), we get D<sub>1</sub>: `{}`
- merging the two dictionaries yields `{ String -> std::vector<int> }`, thus `String` is deduced to be `std::vector<int>`

3) **Two** template parameters `String` and `T` exist

- pattern matching `std::vector<char>` against `String`, we get D<sub>0</sub>: `{ String -> std::vector<char> }`
- pattern matching `std::vector<int>` against `typename First<String>::template ArrayType<T>` we hit a non-deducible context, we get D<sub>1</sub>: `{}`
- merging the two dictionaries yields `{ String -> std::vector<char> }`, which is an incomplete dictionary (`T` is absent) **deduction fails**

I must admit I had not considered yet that the arguments were resolved independently from one another, and therefore than in this last case, when computing D<sub>1</sub> the compiler could not take advantage of the fact that D<sub>0</sub> had already deduced a value for `String`. Why it is done in this fashion, however, is probably a full question of its own.

---

[Without the outer template, it works](http://ideone.com/M41HOR), as in it prints "Specialized":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct First {
    template <typename T>
    using ArrayType = std::vector<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct Second {
    void go() { std::cout << "General\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
struct Second < typename First::template ArrayType<T> > {
    void go() { std::cout << "Specialized\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Second < std::vector<int> > second;
    second.go();
    return 0;
}
```

[Without the inner template, it works](http://ideone.com/e6HVfR), as in it prints "Specialized":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename String>
struct First {
    using ArrayType = std::vector<int>;
};

template <typename String, typename T>
struct Second {
    void go() { std::cout << "General\n"; }
};

template <typename String>
struct Second < String, typename First<String>::ArrayType > {
    void go() { std::cout << "Specialized\n"; }
};


int main() {
    Second < std::vector<int>, std::vector<int> > second;
    second.go();
    return 0;
}
```

[With both, it fails](http://ideone.com/K18pLl), as in it prints "General":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename String>
struct First {
    template <typename T>
    using ArrayType = std::vector<T>;
};

template <typename String, typename T>
struct Second {
    void go() { std::cout << "General\n"; }
};

template <typename String, typename T>
struct Second < String, typename First<String>::template ArrayType<T> > {
    void go() { std::cout << "Specialized\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Second < std::vector<char>, std::vector<int> > second;
    second.go();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice examples. It is to do with non-deduced contexts though, see my answer. The two cases that work do not have to deduce a type from a type name that includes a non-deduced context, as per 14.8.2.5 [temp.deduct.type]/6. In your first example `First` does not need to be deduced. In the second example `First<String>` is a non-deduced context, but `ArrayType` does not need to be deduced. In the third example `First<String>` is a non-deduced context and `T` needs to be deduced, which fails.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: I think I am *starting* to understand the Standard phrasing. So, in essence, the problem seems to be that, *naively*, I would expect `First<String>` to be deduced once `String` is (ie, I would expect a *serial* resolution) however the Standard specifies instead that each argument should be resolved independently (in parallel) and only afterward the deductions' consistency should be checked (because a template parameter can only refer to one type/value/template class). I suppose there is a good reason for this, but I had not expected it!

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Still, if this is truly the case, I do not understand why case (2) works. If the arguments are truly resolved independently, then how could `typename First<String>::ArrayType` be correctly deduced ? Or is it that precisely because any value of `String` would yield the right type (barring specializations), then it is compatible with the value of `String` deduced from the first argument when the time comes for unifying ?

Comment: @MatthieM. The compiler only has to deduce template arguments for each template parameter, not every type in the template argument list. For case (1) it has to deduce `T`, so if `Second<String::ArrayType<X>>` is instantiated then it can deduce `T` as `X`. In case (2) it only has to deduce `String`, because that is the only template parameter, so if `Second<X, Y>` is instantiated it deduces `String` as `X`, and then substitutes it into `typename First<String>::ArrayType` which forms a valid type, and then if `Y` is `First<X>::ArrayType` the specialization matches and is used.

Comment: In (3) it has to deduce _both_ `String` and `T`, but as you say, deduction of each argument happens independently, not left-to-right. In the type name `First<String>::template ArrayType<T>` there is a parameter in a non-deduced context, so no types can be deduced from it at all (if I am reading the standard correctly, which is not guaranteed!) `String` can be deduced from the first argument, but that still leaves `T` undeduced, so deduction fails.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Ah! That clinches. I had lost sight of what we were trying to deduce here. Thank you very much for your thorough follow-up.

Comment: This is very well summed up and a simple yet detailed overview of what is going on, thanks :)

Comment: @Drax: Thanks to you as well, it was a pretty useful exercise for me and I learned something along the process.

Answer (score 2):

> Alternatively what is the best (smallest / cleanest) way to make this work?

Arguably, it is:

- Write a SFINAE trait template `Tr<String,Allocator,T>` that determines whether `T` is the
  same as `basic_data_object<String,Allocator>::array_container<T::E>`
  for some type `E` - *if such there be* - that is `T::value_type`.
- Provide template `get_data_object_value` with a 4th parameter
  defaulting to `Tr<String,Allocator,T>::value`
- Write partial specializations of `get_data_object_value` instantiating that
  4th parameter as `true`, `false` respectively.

Here is a demo program:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator>
struct basic_data_object
{
    template<typename T>
    using array_container = std::vector<T, Allocator<T>>;
};

template<typename T, typename String, template<class> class Allocator>
struct is_basic_data_object_array_container
/* 
    A trait template that has a `static const bool` member `value` equal to
    `true` if and only if parameter type `T` is a container type
    with `value_type E` s.t. 
        `T` = `basic_data_object<String,Allocator>::array_container<T::E>`
*/ 
{
    template<typename A> 
    static constexpr bool
    test(std::is_same<
            A,
            typename basic_data_object<String,Allocator>::template
                array_container<typename A::value_type>
            > *) {
        return std::is_same<
            A,
            typename basic_data_object<String,Allocator>::template
                array_container<typename A::value_type>
            >::value;
    }
    template<typename A> 
    static constexpr bool test(...) {
        return false;
    }
    static const bool value = test<T>(nullptr);
};


template <
    typename String, 
    template<class> class Allocator,
    typename T,
    bool Select = 
        is_basic_data_object_array_container<T,String,Allocator>::value
>           
struct get_data_object_value;


template <
    typename String, 
    template<class> class Allocator,
    typename T
>           
struct get_data_object_value<
    String,
    Allocator,
    T,
    false
>
{
    static void demo() {
        std::cout << "Is NOT a basic_data_object array_container" << std::endl;
    }
};

template <
    typename String, 
    template<class> class Allocator,
    typename T>
struct get_data_object_value<
    String, 
    Allocator,
    T,
    true
>
{
    static void demo() {
        std::cout << "Is a basic_data_object array_container" << std::endl;
    }
};

#include <list>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    get_data_object_value<string,allocator,std::vector<short>>::demo();
    get_data_object_value<string,allocator,std::list<short>>::demo();
    get_data_object_value<string,allocator,short>::demo();
    return 0;
}
```

Built with gcc 4.8.2, clang 3.4. Output:

```
Is a basic_data_object array_container
Is NOT a basic_data_object array_container
Is NOT a basic_data_object array_container
```

VC++ 2013 will not compile this for lack of `constexpr` support. To accommodate that
compiler the following less natural implementation of the trait may be used:

```
template<typename T, typename String, template<class> class Allocator>
struct is_basic_data_object_array_container
{
    template<typename A>
    static
    auto test(
        std::is_same<
            A,
            typename basic_data_object<String, Allocator>::template
                array_container<typename A::value_type>
            > *
        ) ->
            std::integral_constant<
                bool,
                std::is_same<
                    A,
                    typename basic_data_object<String, Allocator>::template
                        array_container<typename A::value_type>
                >::value
            >{}
    template<typename A>
    static std::false_type test(...);
    using type = decltype(test<T>(nullptr));
    static const bool value = type::value;
};
```

Comment: @Danvil Thanks but don't' see my way there; did something else.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: This answer only works because of a bug in GCC 4.8.1

---

Your code works as expected if you drop the keyword `template` in your specialization:

```
template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator, typename T>
struct get_data_object_value
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "general" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename String, template<class> class Allocator, typename T>
struct get_data_object_value
<String, Allocator,
typename basic_data_object<String, Allocator>::array_container<T>>
//                                         ^^^^^^ no template!
{
    void foo() { std::cout << "special" << std::endl; }
};
```

Example tested with GCC 4.8.1:

```
int main()  {
    get_data_object_value<std::string,std::allocator,std::vector<int>> obj;
    obj.foo(); // prints "special"
}
```

Comment: This code is illegal. `template` keyword cannot be omitted here. And the problem is not in it.

Comment: @Constructor: Please cite the corresponding section in the standard.

Comment: @Danvil clang 3.4 does reject it, however.

Comment: @MikeKinghan: That's sad. I still did not found a good cite from the standard which states if it is forbidden or allowed...

Comment: See [temp.names] 14.2/4. And answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: As mentioned: GCC 4.8.1

Comment: @Constructor you forgot to define `basic_data_object`. If you fix that then it **does** compile with GCC 4.8.1, and 4.8.2, but not 4.9.0 and later.